# Litelement - Table sorting renders wrong values

Tags: javascript, sorting, checkbox, styling, lit-element

I am trying to sort an HTML table based on it's values in my Lit element. However, I'm running into a problem with my component. Here is an overview of my table;
[image]

**The problem**

In this application, you need to be able to sort on every table header. However, items which are considered 'done' need to move to the bottom of the table. My problem arises whenever I mark an item as done. In the following example I will mark the top todo (task: 123) as done. The expected behaviour is that the todo is moved to the bottom of the table with it's checkbox enabled. This is not however what is the outcome at the moment.

[image]

As you can see, the todo item with task 123 is moved to the bottom. However, the todo with task 456 also gets it's checkbox marked. This is not desired behaviour and I don't know what's causing it. You can also see that the colors are not correct (this is some styling to show you that a changed todo is being saved, yellow = saving, green = saved and red = error).

**Things I have tried**

Since I don't know what is exactly causing this issue I don't know what I should do. I gave all my inputs/rows/td's id's to make sure nothing gets mixed up, but that doesn't seem to work.

**Code**

```
import { LitElement, html, css } from 'lit-element';

class TableList extends LitElement {
    static get properties() {
        return {
            data: {
                type: Array
            },
            primaryKey: {
                type: String
            },
            defaultSortKey: {
                type: String
            }
        };
    }

    set data(value) {
        let oldValue = this._data;
        this._data = [ ... value];
        this.sortByHeader();
        this.requestUpdate('data', oldValue);
    }

    get data() {
        return this._data;
    }
    
    async edit(entry, key, event) {
        this.shadowRoot.getElementById('entry' + entry[this.primaryKey].value).classList.remove('saved');
        this.shadowRoot.getElementById('entry' + entry[this.primaryKey].value).classList.remove('error');
        this.shadowRoot.getElementById('entry' + entry[this.primaryKey].value).classList.add('saving');

        if (entry[key].type === "checkbox") {
            entry[key].value = event.target.checked;
        } else {
            entry[key].value = event.target.value;
        }

        if (await update(entry)) {
            this.shadowRoot.getElementById('entry' + entry[this.primaryKey].value).classList.remove('saving');
            this.shadowRoot.getElementById('entry' + entry[this.primaryKey].value).classList.add('saved');

            setTimeout(() => {
                this.shadowRoot.getElementById('entry' + entry[this.primaryKey].value).classList.remove('saved');
            }, 1000);
        } else {
            this.shadowRoot.getElementById('entry' + entry[this.primaryKey].value).classList.remove('saving');
            this.shadowRoot.getElementById('entry' + entry[this.primaryKey].value).classList.add('error');

            setTimeout(() => {
                this.shadowRoot.getElementById('entry' + entry[this.primaryKey].value).classList.remove('error');
            }, 5000);
        }
    }

    sortByHeader(key) {       
        if (key === undefined) {
            key = this.defaultSortKey;
        }

        let oldValue = this.data;
        this._data = [ ... this.data.sort((a, b) => {
            return a[this.defaultSortKey].value - b[this.defaultSortKey].value 
                        || a[key].value - b[key].value;
        })];

        this.requestUpdate('data', oldValue);
    }

    renderHeaders() {
        let keys = Object.keys(this.data[0]);

        return keys.map(key => html`
            ${this.data[0][key].visible ?
                html`
                    <th id="${'header' + key}" @click="${() => this.sortByHeader(key)}">
                        ${key}
                    </th>
                `: ''
            }
        `)
    }

    renderRows() {
        return this.data.map(entry => html`
        <tr id="${'entry' + entry[this.primaryKey].value}">
            ${Object.keys(entry).map(key => html`
                ${entry[key].visible && !entry[key].editable ?
                    html`<td>${entry[key].value}</td>`
                    : ``
                }
                ${entry[key].visible && entry[key].editable ?
                    html`<td id="${'td' + key + entry[this.primaryKey].value}">
                            <input
                                id="${'input' + key + entry[this.primaryKey].value}"
                                name="${'input' + key + entry[this.primaryKey].value}"
                                type="${entry[key].type}"
                                ?checked="${entry[key].value}"
                                value="${entry[key].value}"
                                @change="${(event) => {
                                    this.edit(entry, key, event)
                                }}"
                            />
                        </td>`
                    : ``
                }
            `)}
        </tr>
        `)
    }

    render() {
        return html`
            <table id="table-list">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        ${this.renderHeaders()}
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    ${this.renderRows()}
                </tbody>
            </table>
      `;
    }

    static get styles() {
        return css`
            table {
                width: 100%;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }

            th {
                padding-top: 12px;
                padding-bottom: 12px;
                text-align: center;
                background-color: #4CAF50;
                color: white;
            }

            tr {
                text-align: right;
                -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in;
                -o-transition: all .2s ease-in;
                -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
                transition: all .2s ease-in;
                background: white; 
                padding: 20px;
            }

            .disabled {
                color: lightgrey;
            }

            .saving {
                background: yellow;
            }

            .saved {
                background: lightgreen;
            }

            .error {
                background: red;
            }

            .sort:after {
                content: ' ↓';
            }
        `;
    }
}

export default TableList;
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to create your own get/set methods for `data`. That's done for you since `data` is a property. You need to be looking for changes to `data` in LitElement's `updated(changedProperties)` method.

Comment: @Thad But I want to order the list as soon as it's gets set, so I have to overwrite it.

Comment: Perhaps this will help you with sorting table by column with icons in lit-elements https://jsabarinath.wordpress.com/2021/03/12/how-to-create-a-sorting-table-with-icons-in-lit-elements-and-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you are using array with id in template use repeat function of lit-html

   import { repeat } from "lit-html/directives/repeat";
2. For styling don't add classes to DOM manually. Use classMap from lit-html

   import { classMap } from "lit-html/directives/class-map";

I fixed your checkbox issue please follow this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-lqykem).

For more information about lit-html please refer to their [documentation](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/).